# How to solve the optimality equation? (Markov decision process)

Tags: markov-process, operations-research, dynamic-programming

I'm struggling with this problem I have to solve, I have attached the problem below. I have done some questions that are similar but I have given simple values for 'a' and 's'. If someone could help me please that would be appreciated.
 [image]
Thank you.

Comment: Hint: to get started, simplify the optimality equation for $t=2$.

Comment: I'll try :/ I'm pretty bad at this stuff. V3 is 0 right?

Comment: Yes, $V_3=0$, so the $E[]$ part disappears.

Comment: So V2=c(s,a), where do I go from there? and I have no idea how to calculate a*

Answer (score 1):

To start, consider $t=2$:
\begin{align}
V_2(s)
&=\min_{a\in A} \{c(s,a)+E[V_3(Y)|s,a]\}\\
&=\min_{a\in A} \{a^2+s^2+E[0]\}\\
&=\min_{a\in A} \{a^2+s^2\}
=0^2+s^2
=s^2,
\end{align}
with minimizer $a_3^*(s)=0$.

Next,
\begin{align}
V_1(s)
&=\min_{a\in A} \{c(s,a)+E[V_2(Y)|s,a]\}\\
&=\min_{a\in A} \{a^2+s^2+E[V_2(s+a+\xi)]\}\\
&=\min_{a\in A} \{a^2+s^2+E[(s+a+\xi)^2]\}\\
&=\min_{a\in A} \{a^2+s^2+E[(s+a)^2+2(s+a)\xi+\xi^2]\}\\
&=\min_{a\in A} \{a^2+s^2+(s+a)^2+2(s+a)E[\xi]+E[\xi^2]\}\\
&=\min_{a\in A} \{a^2+s^2+(s+a)^2+2(s+a)0+1\}\\
&=\min_{a\in A} \{2a^2+2as+2s^2+1\}
=3s^2/2+1,
\end{align}
with minimizer $a_2^*(s)=-s/2$.

Finally,
\begin{align}
V_0(s)
&=\min_{a\in A} \{c(s,a)+E[V_1(Y)|s,a]\}\\
&=\min_{a\in A} \{a^2+s^2+E[V_1(s+a+\xi)]\}\\
&=\min_{a\in A} \{a^2+s^2+E[3(s+a+\xi)^2/2+1]\}\\
&=\min_{a\in A} \{a^2+s^2+3E[(s+a)^2+2(s+a)\xi+\xi^2]/2+1\}\\
&=\min_{a\in A} \{a^2+s^2+3(s+a)^2/2+3(s+a)E[\xi]+3E[\xi^2]/2+1\}\\
&=\min_{a\in A} \{a^2+s^2+3(s+a)^2/2+3(s+a)0+3\cdot 1/2+1\}\\
&=\min_{a\in A} \{5 a^2/2 + 3 a s + 5 s^2/2 + 5/2\}
=8s^2/5+5/2,
\end{align}
with minimizer $a_1^*(s)=-3s/5$.